# Intercept GitHub Workflow Cancellation on Docker Container

Tags: docker, containers, github-actions, workflow

I am running tests on **GitHub Actions** using a Workflow that uses a **custom Docker image** I've created.

When **cancelling the Workflow**, GitHub **kills the docker container** as per [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/canceling-a-workflow#steps-github-takes-to-cancel-a-workflow-run).

Is there a way to intercept the "kill" of the container so that I could run some teardown commands in the container before terminating it?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible at least by defining a custom action with a custom entrypoint script.

While you cannot use `--entrypoint` in default containerized action [(as noted here)](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/running-jobs-in-a-container#setting-container-resource-options), you can create your own action and define an entrypoint script where you can trap the SIGINT GitHub send to the container:

> For steps that need to be canceled, the runner machine sends SIGINT/Ctrl-C to the step's entry process (docker for container action). If the process doesn't exit within 7500 ms, the runner will send SIGTERM/Ctrl-Break to the process, then wait for 2500 ms for the process to exit. If the process is still running, the runner kills the process tree.

### Custom action

Here's an example of a custom action in my repository. I have the following structure:

```
repository
├── .github
│   ├── actions
│   │   └── test-teri
│   │       ├── Dockerfile
│   │       ├── action.yml
│   │       └── entrypoint.sh
│   └── workflows
│       └── cd_workflow.yml
```

The Dockerfile is just a copy from [GH actions documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-docker-container-action).

```
FROM alpine:3.10

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

In entrypoint.sh I have the beef of the process:

```bash
#!/bin/sh -l

trap cleanup SIGINT

cleanup() {
    sleep 2
    echo "Cleanup successful."
    exit
}

while true
do
    echo "Testing..."
    sleep 1
done
```

I'm trapping the `SIGINT` signal within the entrypoint and calling the cleanup function when that happens. This script just normally prints `Testing...` infinitely to the output, but you can define your entrypoint in a way that it calls other stuff based on your `run:` instruction in workflow or however you want. I won't go into detail on that.

Remember to give execution permissions to the entrypoint sript, otherwise it won't run.

Finally, my action.yml, where you define the Dockerfile used to run this action.

```
# action.yml
name: 'Hello World'
description: 'Test sigint'
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'Dockerfile'
```

### Running the workflow

Then, you just need to use this custom action in your workflow.

```
name: Test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - so-test # <- Whatever branch you are using

jobs:
  build:
    name: "SO test build"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Test action with sigint
        uses: ./.github/actions/test-teri
```

### Testing sigint

Now when I run the workflow and cancel it after a while, the following can be seen in the log:

```
Testing...
Testing...
Testing...
Testing...
Testing...
Testing...
Testing...
Cleanup successful.
Error: The operation was canceled.
```

You notice that the cleanup function has been executed. But do notice that the time limit to run that is that 7500ms, so it needs to succeed in that time. I'm not aware if you can customize that time in any way in GH actions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. That put me on the right track. I have been able to successfully trap using your script. However, when I replace your testing loop with another command (python -m pytest tests -n 4 -k my_tests), the cleanup() function does not get called.  Any idea why?

Comment: Hard to say. I did not test with GH again, but for me the script seems to go to cleanup properly locally when I'm running pytest within the bash script.